# Overlap leading Icon on form input field in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-layout

Trying to implement this style of login in flutter. Any ideas? Tried using the prefix icon and row but not really getting it.
[Example Login Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZpVp.png)

Comment: Post what you have tried and platform member contribute. This is not the way of working stackoverlow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `Stack` with two children, one for the leading icon and the other for the text input. I wrote the code you need to implement what you want. So, I will share it with you. You only have to set up the colors and the text style as you prefer.

Here we go...

```js
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0),
          height: 36.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
            boxShadow: [BoxShadow(blurRadius: 12.0)],
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70.0, 0.0, 30.0, 0.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: 'Username',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            boxShadow: [BoxShadow(blurRadius: 12.0)],
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    SizedBox(height: 12.0),
    Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0),
          height: 36.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
            boxShadow: [BoxShadow(blurRadius: 12.0)],
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70.0, 0.0, 30.0, 0.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: 'Password',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            boxShadow: [BoxShadow(blurRadius: 12.0)],
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.lock_outline),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

And the output is this:

[image: Login Example]

Comment: @Samuel Paintsil you're welcome. If you think the answer is the solution you are looking for, please mark it as answered. Thanks in advance